# Using Indexing When Performing JOINs on Part of a Composite Key

Tags: index, mariadb, join, index-tuning, sqlalchemy

I have a table in my database (hosted on MariaDB) that looks like this (I have given the definition in SQLAlchemy),

```
class Address(Base):
__tablename__ = 'address'
__table_args__ = {'schema': DB_NAME}

referenceID = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=25), primary_key=True)
referenceTable = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=25), primary_key=True)
sourceReferenceID = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=25), primary_key=True)
addressType = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=25), primary_key=True)
zip = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=10))
streetAddress = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=50))
city = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=25))
fullAddress = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=200))
country = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=25))
validFrom = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
validTo = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
```

Now, it can be seen that my table has a composite key which includes several attributes.

As far as I know, a clustered index will be created out of the primary key of a table. I am not completely aware of how this works when the table consists of a composite key. An explanation on this would be appreciated.

Further, I am going to want to perform several JOINs on this table, particularly using the `referenceID` and `sourceReferenceID` attributes of the table. To do this efficiently, do I need to create indexes (non-clustered) on these attributes separately using `index=True`?

Comment: If your index for the primary key contains columns x,y,z and your predicate is using x or x,y or x,y,z that will be fine. Some DBMS can utilize an index via skip scans, but in general for any combination of y,z without x in the predicate, the index will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` on any column or combination of columns (except for `TEXT` or `BLOB`).

`JOINing` is likely to be faster (perhaps much faster) if the columns in the `ON` clause are in some index.

I don't understand the semantics of your four primary key columns; the rest of the columns feel like they need a `location_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY`.

I MySQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` has these properties:

- There is only one PK for the table.
- "Clustered":  The Data's BTree is ordered by the PK.  This makes *some* queries with `WHERE` or `ON` involving the PK column(s) faster than they would otherwise be.
- The order of columns in the PK (and any secondary key) is important, depending on details of the `SELECT` or other SQL that is using it.
- A "composite" (multi-column) index (`PRIMARY` or secondary) can be though of as concatenating the columns together to make one long string that provides the storage order of the data (for Primary) or index (for secondary).
- Usually, if the first column of a composite key is not tested with `=`, the rest of the columns are not used.
- A "covering" index is one that includes *all* of the columns needed for the *entire* `SELECT`.  This is likely to make the Select run somewhat faster because it need look only in the index's BTree.

It would be better to discuss a specific *query*.